# Finding saddle point of a quadratic form

Tags: optimization

I am trying to find the saddle point of a quadratic form:
$$f(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{x}^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{c}$$
using a minimization/maximization-like algorithm. Is there such solution method available somewhere? I want to avoid the $\nabla\cdot f(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{0}$ approach because I later want to add inequality constraints. The point that I am seeking is a maximum in one direction and a minimum in all other directions.

**edit** The above problem comes from the following formulation: imagine an externally forced one degree-of-freedom oscillator whose displacement $u(t)$ satisfies the equation of motion:
$$m\ddot{u}+ku=f \cos \omega t$$
where $m$ and $k$ are respectively the mass and stiffness of the oscillator; $f$ and $\omega$ defines the forcing term. I would like to use a modified version of Hamilton's principle to find the forced steady state solution (the transient part is ignored). Since I am interested in periodic orbits only, the sought (periodic) solution satisfies:
$$\delta\bigl(\int_0^T \frac{1}{2} m \dot{u}^2- \frac{1}{2} k u^2+fu\cos \omega t \,\mathrm{d}t\bigr)=0\quad;\quad u(0)=u(T)\quad;\quad \dot{u}(0)=\dot{u}(T)\qquad(1)$$
where $T=2\pi/\omega$. As the Hamilton's principle says, the solution is an extremum of the underlying functional, not a minimum necessarily.

I now want to find an approximation of $u(t)$, as for instance:
$$u(t)=a_1+a_2\cos\omega t + a_3\sin \omega t\qquad (2)$$
where $a_1$, $a_2$, and $a_3$ have to be found. I just have to plug (2) in (1) and find the point $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ that makes the functional stationary. For reasons that are not given here, I would like to reformulate this in a $\max\min$ problem since I know for this specific case that the solution is a saddle point, *ie* a maximum along $a_1$ and a minimum along $(a_2,a_3)$. The quadratic form given at the top of the message comes from plugging (2) in (1) with $\mathbf{x}=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$.

Comment: How would you define the saddle point of an inequality-constrained problem?

Comment: Let us note $\mathbf{x}=\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ then the problem would be: find $\max_{x_0}\min_{x_1,\dots,x_n}\; f(\mathbf{x})$ under linear inequality constraints $\mathbf{G}\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{q}\leq 0$. Not sure if it makes sense but it would be something like that.

Comment: Could you look for local extrema where $\nabla f = 0$ and then also consider the boundary of the constraint region? Compare and choose the point you desire? At a local extreme you can determine the nature of the critical point $p$ ( $\nabla f (p)=0$) by shifting variables at the point to write $f(y) = f(p)+y^TMy$. The eigenvalues of $M$ indicate if the point is min/max or saddle or trough.

Comment: It may be doable when $n$ is small but I'd say that it would quickly becomes intractable as $n$ increases. Knowing that the solution of the unconstrained problem is a saddle is no the difficulty. The difficulty is about how to formulate the problem with linear inequalities within a $\max\min$ strategy. The first question is: is the formulation correct?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you specify,
$$\min f(x)=x^TAx+x^Tb$$
subject to
$$Gx-q\leq 0$$
is a quadraric programming problem. See [the wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming) for solution procedures.

For the saddle point, rather than the minimum, the conjugate residual method is developed to find this point.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on the "conjugate residual method": it looks interesting. The problem I was specifying was not a $\min f$, in the sense of finding a minimum of $f$, but rather a $\min\max f$ (not sure about the relevance of the notation) in the sense of finding saddle points.

Comment: By the way, do you know if this conjugate residual method generalizes to cases with inequality constraints?

Comment: @pluton I've not studied the algorithm in detail, but I suspect that it may be able to be generalised to use with constraints. Look up null space method, which can be used to effectively remove the constraints.

Comment: I think that the null space method is also called the "active-set" method. Anyway, I'll have a look. I'm surprised that there is nothing available in usual soft packages. I'm suspecting something wrong in the formulation. Thanks

Comment: $min max f$, minimization with respect to which variable and maximization with respect to what?